# Hazelcast cardinality estimator local instance

Tags: microservices, hazelcast, cardinality-estimation

I have an incoming stream of values at a rate of a few millions per minute going through my services cluster. I would like to get a count of the unique values going through all of the instances in a given time frame. I am looking at Hazelcast's Cardinality estimator to do the job but I'm not sure if this will be a bottleneck since updating a value in a distributed datastrucure takes time. Is there a configuration that allows Hazelcast to create a local instance to act as a buffer? Or maybe a method for dealing with such a high throughput income rate.

I am stuck and don't seem to find any useful documentation on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

To get an estimate (not count) of unique values across all members, it is not possible to eliminate all network traffic. Would it be useful to estimate within a member?